# Java EE at creating servlet - Multiple markers at this line

Tags: java-ee-6, java-ee-7, java-ee-8, java-ee-5

So I have this problem (multiple markers at this line) whenever I create a servlet i dont know why,

[This is the basic servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRAhO.png)

Comment: There are error messages hidden behind the red underlines. Try reading those. We can't do it for you, your image does not support that kind of interaction.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)